# How to describe when comparing two columns and extracting mismatches in R

Tags: r, compare, extract

I want to compare the two columns in R and extract any discrepancies.
I came up with the following method or `all.equal()`, `setdiff()`, but it doesn't extract specific parts.

### Could you tell me what kind of methods are available?

Thank you for your response.
I renewed it after being pointed out.
The results can be in any form as long as you know different parts.

### The data is as follows:

```
#original data

age1 age2
63   63
66   66
46   46
63   63
66   66
46   46
63   63
66   66
46   46
63   63
66   66
46   46
63   6
66   66
46   46

#script-----------------------------------------
data1 = read.csv("data1.csv",header = TRUE, na.strings="")
data1 = data1$age1
data2 = data1$age2

identical(data1$age1, data1$age1)

#result------------------------------------------------
[1]FALSE
```

Comment: What does the `13` mean? An index or discrepant value in `data1$age`?

Comment: Please also include your data, `dput(data1)` and `dput(data2)` .